# pytorch load checkpoints to continue training - zero_grad() or not?

Tags: pytorch

I have saved and loaded the checkpoints as per the pytorch manual, and it all seems OK. Now, usually, when I want to start training, I have something like this in pytorch:

```
    for itr in range(1, args.niters + 1):
        optimizer.zero_grad() # should I or should I not when checkpoints are loaded?
```

I am unsure if I should do `zero_grad()` here (which I use when I start training from scratch), since I am reloading all my weights and bias.

Apologies if this is a daft question.

Comment: do you mean when you partially train your model and now want to continue training ?

Comment: Short answer is yes you should zero your gradients. Long answer will depend on your specific training code but unless you're doing something like accumulating gradients from many .backward passes before stepping the optimizer then it won't won't hurt to zero the grads.